# Compare two Ranges In Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare data from two ranges. "A" contains 1,2,3,4 and "B" contains 1,2,5. I want to find those that are in "B" but not in "A", which is 5. Below is my code but I can't seem to get what I want. Can someone please advise?

```
Dim a As Range, b As Range, i As Integer, x As Integer
Set a = Range("A1:A4")
Set b = Range("B1:B3")

For i = 1 To b.Count
  For x = 1 To a.Count

    If b(i, 1) = a(x, 1) Then

    Else
      MsgBox (b(i, 1))
      Exit For
    End If
  Next x
Next i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very small range but still I would recommend using Arrays to store your range values and then use the arrays for comparison. See this example.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ar1, Ar2
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Found As Boolean

    Ar1 = Range("A1:A4"): Ar2 = Range("B1:B3")

    For i = LBound(Ar2) To UBound(Ar2)
        Found = False
        For j = LBound(Ar1) To UBound(Ar1)
            If Ar1(j, 1) = Ar2(i, 1) Then
                Found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If Found = False Then Debug.Print Ar2(i, 1) & " Is unique"
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Another way (*I still prefer the above way though*)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim Found As Boolean

    Set rngA = Range("A1:A4"): Set rngB = Range("B1:B3")

    For Each aCell In rngB
        Found = False
        For Each bCell In rngA
            If bCell.Value = aCell.Value Then
                Found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If Found = False Then Debug.Print aCell.Value & " Is unique"
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

or, if you'd like a non-VBA solution using Excel worksheet functions, try this formula in a column like Column C

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(B:B,A:A)),B:B&" is not found","")`

[image]

Philip

Comment: Good 1! I prefer yours to mine if OP is ready for a non VBA solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I tend to prefer native VBA functions like Find(). I find them a bit faster to use, especially when you're working with a large range.

Here's another solution:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim r1 As Excel.Range
    Dim r2 As Excel.Range

    Set r1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A4")
    Set r2 = Sheet1.Range("B1:B3")

    Dim s() As String

    s = getUniques(r1, r2)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(s)
        Debug.Print s(i)
    Next i
End Sub


Function getUniques(ByRef r1 As Excel.Range, ByRef r2 As Excel.Range) As String()
    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim found As Excel.Range

    Dim uniques() As String
    Dim i As Long

    For Each cell In r2
        On Error Resume Next
        Set found = r1.Find(cell.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If (found Is Nothing) Then
            ReDim Preserve uniques(i)
            uniques(i) = cell.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    getUniques = uniques
End Function
```